# HTTP Error 500.19 - IIS and MIME Type not working in windows10?

Tags: iis, iis-7, mime-types

I am trying to run my asp.net mvc website on the IIS. I got the following error:

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error The requested page cannot be
>   accessed because the related configuration data for the page is
>   invalid.

I use IIS through IIS manager and when I try to configure MIME Types in IIS Manager, I got the following config error:

> There was an error while performing this operation. Error: Cannot add
>   duplicate collection entry of type 'mimeMap' with unique key attribute
>   'fileExtension' set to '.woff2'.

As a result of my detailed research, this problem occurs on IIS 7.5. How to get rid of this errors and run my web page on IIS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first, try to install iis rewrite module to told IIS my custom web.config is not failure or faulty. If it's not fix the problem, I suggest another solution particularly for your problem. Delete your .wolf2 config from your web.config file. For example;

```
<staticContent>
   <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
</staticContent>
```

Delete mimeMap row which has .woff2 file extension from the staticContent. It would fix your problem because this error says that I already have .wolf2 in my config file but you trying to add one more.

Comment: i tried your last mentioned sentence and delete mimeMap and it works perfect. thanks :)